# Can Totem play from last position only for videos?

Tags: 11.04, video, totem, playback

I have Totem player configured in its options to resume playback from the last position. But it does this for both video and audio files. But, I want it only for the video files so I can resume from where I left off, but not for music files. I want music files to start from the beginning always. Is there any way to force this?

Currently I have to use a separate music player, but I don't really want another player just for music.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see, no. You'd need to edit the source code and add the functionality yourself. Or you could put a feature request in gnome.org for totem