# Videos not resume from last position

Tags: 14.04, video, totem

My default Ubuntu player "Videos" (Totem) doesn't resume from last position. The settings in preferences called "Start playing files from last position" is ***already checked*** yet it always starts all the movies from beginning. What should I do?

**NOTE:**

- Ubuntu 14.04
- System fully updated (till today)

I have tried searching in askubuntu regarding this problem but all I could get were:

1. [VLC last position](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164233/how-do-i-resume-video-play-from-the-point-it-was-stopped-with-vlc)
2. [Last position only for video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46384/can-totem-play-from-last-position-only-for-videos)

Comment: Try reinstalling the package and check the box again then reboot your PC

Answer (score 1):

***SOLUTION***: (from Olu Doug's comment) :

I removed the "Videos" package from Ubuntu Software Center and reinstalled it with all the recommended plug-ins. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

well after playing around with Totem for a while the only thing I can think of is that the vid has to be longer than 3 min for Totem to actually apply the position save of the chosen file...If it's any shorter, I guess you could maybe add a chapter in the file before closing...

Comment: In my case all are full length movies